# Check if class have skip before action for test in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is possible to check if a controller have a `skip_before_action` for one specific action?

For example:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user
    ...
end
```

And then check with something like this:

```
AuthenticationController.has_skip_before_action(:authenticate_user)?
```

I want to do this check for my controllers tests. If RSpec has anything like this, I can use. I am using Rails 5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should you? No. Similar to what [Veridian Dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55283846/33226) wrote, you want to test behaviour not necessarily the existence of a method.

That said, is it possible to do so? Yes. Here's a toy example that'll work for you:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user

  def index
  end
end

# authentication_controller_spec.rb
test "should get index" do
  # Have to make a request first to instantiate the controller variable
  get authentication_url

  # Convert this to a clearer method in your real code
  result = controller.__callbacks.first.last.map(&:filter).include?(:authenticate_user)

  # Assert on result ...
end
```

To explain the code, you're using the instance of AuthenticationController and digging into the private methods of that instance to get the list of callbacks. Then you can look for the presence or absence of your specific callback.

**This is not a good solution, and I would shudder to see these in a codebase!** This test relies on internal functionality of the Rails framework which could change at anytime. That makes a test like this brittle and it can fail during framework upgrades. Any colleague checking this code in would require a very specific explanation on why this was an absolute necessity to have in our codebase.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can check to see if `:authenticate_user` is working as expected by validating that it either *does* or *does not* do what you intend.

As with all unit tests, it's not about "does this method exist?", it's about "does this method do what we expect?" If the method does not exist, we do not check for that because we do not care. We want the behavior to match our expectations, not the code. If our code does not match our expectations, we must investigate, read, refactor, etc. But that is a human job, not an RSpec job.

I assume that you're just trying to be DRY and avoid checking authentication if "skip_before_authentication" already exists, but that's a really bad idea even if it were possible.